# What's the best way in PHP to assign to a variable depending on two independent conditions (-> four possible values)?

Tags: php, boolean, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

I have a variable that needs to be assigned one of four possible values, depending on two conditions.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
if (conditionsOne) {
  $foo = (conditionTwo) ? 'one' : 'two';
} else {
  $foo = (conditionTwo) ? 'three' : 'four';
}
```

But this, IMHO, slightly hurts the "golden rule" of programming which says "never write the same code twice" (if someone changes `conditionTwo` and forgets to change the other `conditionTwo` we have a bug).

I also could write this as a nested ternary, but this also needed two times the condition and would be less readable.

Is there any way in PHP to do such assignment without code-doubling (so no checking twice for the same condition) and without hurting readability?

Answer (score 1):

Store the result, and use a `switch`:

```
$s = 0;

if (conditionOne) {
  $s += 1;
}
if ($conditionTwo) {
  $s += 10;
}

switch ($s) {
   case 0: $foo = 'four'; break;
   case 1: $foo = 'two'; break;
   case 10: $foo = 'three'; break;
   case 11: $foo = 'one'; break;
}
```

Comment: Interesting way! I didn't thought this way.

Answer (score 0):

that should works...

```
$values=array(array(“four”,”three”),array(“two”,”one”));
$foo=$values[$conditionsOne][$conditionsTwo];
```

Comment: I doubt you can (should?) index an array with a boolean.

Comment: why not ? if you are looking for concise way to write that, then you can , otherwise use plain if else or switch

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this way would be better, but you can make a function and use "return" to
optimize comparations:

```
function cond( $conditionsOne, $conditionsTwo )
{
    if( $conditionsOne && !$conditionsTwo ) return 'one';
    if( $conditionsOne ) return 'two';
    if( $conditionsTwo ) return 'three';
    return 'four';
}

$foo = cond( $conditionsOne, $conditionsTwo );
```